# Auto rename of the same filename in uploading file PHP code

Tags: php

multiple_upload.php

This code below is the multiple_upload.php it has 2 buttons for upload and a submit button.
actual picture of it:

```
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form action="multiple_upload_ac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td><strong>multiple Files Upload </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select file 
<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select file
<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

multiple_upload_ac.php

this code will process the file that you put in this line of code `<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" />` it will save inside my upload folder.

```
<?php

//set where you want to store files
//in this example we keep file in folder upload 
//$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name']; = upload file name
//for example upload file name cartoon.gif . $path will be upload/cartoon.gif

$path1= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
$path2= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];


//copy file to where you want to store file
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], $path2);

// Use this code to display the error or success.

$filesize1=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][0];
$filesize2=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][1];


if($filesize1 || $filesize2!= 0) 
{
echo "We have recieved your files";
}
else {
echo "ERROR.....";
}

// What files that have a problem? (if found)

if($filesize1==0) {
echo "There're something error in your first file";
echo "<BR />";
}

if($filesize2==0) {
echo "There're something error in your second file";
echo "<BR />";
}
?>
```

Here is my Question:
If it's possible for example, I upload samplefile.ppt and the other user upload a same filename and file type(samplefile.ppt).. if is posible the newly upload will have a filename like samplefile(1).ppt or samplefile_1.ppt because there was a exsisting file, and when other user upload again, the file will became samplefile(2).ppt or samplefile_2.ppt.
thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if the file already exists before you copy them.

If it exists, change the file name to what you want, and I will also recommend you to do all these things in a loop, **don't repeat yourself**.

Like following:

```
if( file_exists($path1) ) {
    // change another filename to overwrite $path1
}
```

Sorry about that I forgot to check if the file exists even it have a count, so you will have some more complicated work to do other than a simple if, following is the edited code:

```
for( $i = 0; isset($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]); $i++ ) {
    /*
     * do things before copy
     */
    $path = 'upload/'.$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];
    $lastDot = strrpos($path, '.');
    $base = substr($file, 0, $lastDot);
    $ext = substr($file, $lastDot);
    // this loop will keep doing until find a path that no file exists
    for( $seq = 0; file_exists($path); $seq++ ) {
        if( file_exists($path) ) {
            $path = $base . '_'. $seq. $ext;
        }
    }
    /*
     *  do copy and something else
     */
}
```

Comment: What do you want for the exact code?
Just some string operation in that if expression.

Comment: And you would better stop using $HTTP_POST_FILES, because it's deprecated [in the official manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

Comment: Apparently you can handle all you want after copied the files, like I commented in the code `do copy and something else`, I don't think I supposed to answer a piece of code for THAT, which if you have a database related to it, you should know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check before copying and [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for the file information, e.g.:

```
$file = $HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0];
$path_info = pathinfo($file);
$count = 0;

while(file_exists($file) {
    $count ++;
    $file = $path_info['dirname'] . $path_info['filename'] '_' . $count . '.' $path_info['extension'];
}

copy($file, $path) ;
```